# Gap in Hartshorne I can't fill

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Page 142, Example 6.11.4.

I've been trying to go through the details of the sentence

*The proof of (6.10) shows that if $f \in K$ is invertible at $Z$, then the principal divisor $(f)$ on $X - Z$ has degree $0$.*

$X$ is the singular curve given by the homogeneous equation $y^2z = x^3$ in $\mathbb P^2$ and $Z$ is the singular point $[0,0,1]$. $K$ is the field of rational functions of $X$. (6.10) refers to the result that a principal divisor on a complete nonsingular curve has degree $0$.

So first of all $X$ is not nonsingular, so I guess the idea is to relax all the statements involved and still get the proof. My main issue is that the morphism $X - Z \to \mathbb P^1$ is **not** finite (it is not proper and finite morphisms are). Everything in the section was about finite morphisms of curves with nonsingularity assumptions almost everywhere, so this is a pain. I understand that the morphism $\varphi : X \to \mathbb P^1$ obtained from the field extension $k(f) \subseteq K(X)$ will be finite and $X$ is complete, but then the map $\varphi^* : \mathrm{Div}(\mathbb P^1) \to \mathrm{Div}(X)$ assumes $X$ is nonsingular, and I don't see how to correctly get rid of the issue of the singular point.

I thought about using the projection from a point $\mathbb P^3 \backslash \{*\} \to \mathbb P^2$ which sends a twisted cubic $C$ to this singular curve $X$, and since the induced morphism $C \to X$ is a bijection of sets, the induced morphism of complete nonsingular curves $C \to X \to \mathbb P^1$ would give me a Weil divisor on $C$, which I could pushforward to $X - Z$ using the fact that if $P \in C$ is the point which maps to $Z$, then the map $C \to X$ restricts to an isomorphism $C - P \to X - Z$, so I can push my Weil divisor of $C - P$ to $X - Z$. This seems to be a correct approach, but if it was the only one, it would have deserved a comment from Hartshorne...

Added : to show that principal Cartier divisors of $X$ have a Weil divisor of degree $0$ on $X - Z$, I encounter similar issues.

So my question is : does anyone know exactly what was the intended meaning of the sentence I quoted above?

Comment: @RghtHndSd : Added.

Comment: Is "moral"  really the word you want to use in the title?

Comment: @SergioParreiras : Well the result and its proof might be correct, modulo adding a ton of details, so that's it's not really a mistake but morally there should have been details. That's what I mean. And a funny title always attracts readers like you. =D

Comment: Yes: I came hoping to see some clash of ethics and mathematics...

Comment: @SergioParreiras : Of course not. The word moral is more used in the same sense that we sometimes say "morally this is the proof" or "morally this is true". No philosophy involved here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corollary I.6.10 states that every nonsingular quasi-projective curve is isomorphic to an open subset of a nonsingular projective curve. Thus we have $X - Z \subset W$ where $W$ is a projective nonsingular curve. Now the morphism $X - Z \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ extends uniquely to $W$, and we can apply Theorem 6.10.

Comment: I know, but since it was an example I wanted the explicit construction : in this case I believe that the twisted cubic projected to $\mathbb P^2$ is the curve $W$ you described above and the open immersion $X - Z \to W$ comes from this construction. So you're saying Hartshorne probably meant "desingularize and compute Weil divisors"?

Comment: Since $W$ is complete the morphism $W \to \mathbb P^1$ will be finite by Proposition 6.8, but do I need the morphism $W \to \mathbb P^1$ to be an isomorphism to be able to carry the property "$f$ is invertible at $Z$" back to $W$, so that the coefficient of the divisor remains $0$ at the corresponding point $Z'$ on the desingularized curve?

Comment: The desingularization is given by blowing up the origin. $f$ invertible at $Z$ means that the extension of $f$ to $W \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ will be invertible (with no pole) on $W - (X - Z)$. I am not claiming that Hartshorne probably meant anything, only that this is a quick solution to what you perceive to be a gap.

Comment: I need to think about this more, but thanks for the answer!

Comment: Certainly, let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: I get that since $X - Z$ is an open subset of both $X$ and $W$, we will have $k(X) = k(X-Z)=k(W)$ (the fields of rational functions). But I'm confused with translating the condition "$f$ is invertible at $Z \in X$" to "$f$ is invertible at the points in $W \backslash (X-Z)$", giving me the desired conclusion on the divisors using Corollary 6.10.

Comment: I think this works, tell me what do you think : pick $Q \in W - (X - Z)$ ; by Chapter I, Theorem 6.1A in Hartshorne, the local ring $\mathcal O_{X,Z}$ is dominated by some local ring of $k(X) = k(W)$, but since $W - (X-Z) = \{Q\}$ is a point (because the twisted cubic curve and the projection I described above is an instance of the desingularization process), the local ring $\mathcal O_{X,Z}$ is dominated by $\mathcal O_{W,Q}$. It follows that $f \in \mathcal O_{X,Z}^{\times}$ implies $f \in \mathcal O_{W,Q}^{\times}$ by the assumption of domination.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: That looks great!